# How do I correct the following error code: ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 15) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 16, 1)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm trying to use an LSTM Neural Network to perform a prediction. The data set has 16 X values to every Y value. As far as I can tell there is a problem with the shapes of the train X & Y arrays or the test X & Y arrays or both. I've tried reshaping, it appears my adjustments are not correct. Below is the code along the with output from Jupyter Notebook. Thank you in advance for your insights.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

#import pandas as pd
import tflearn
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

def myRNN():
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    # Network building
    net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 16, 1])
    net = tflearn.lstm(net, 32, dropout=0.8,bias=True)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='relu')
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='mean_square', learning_rate=0.003)

    #Gather the Training Data
    csvData = np.genfromtxt('LabelCall5Data.csv', delimiter=',')
    trainX = csvData[0:3360,0:15]
    trainY = csvData[0:3360,16]

    #Transpose the input Data
    trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (-1, 16, 1))
    trainY = np.reshape(trainY, (-1, 1))
    print('trainX Shape: ', trainX.shape)
    print('trainY Shape: ', trainY.shape)

    #Gather the Testing Data
    testX = csvData[3361:,0:15]
    testY = csvData[3361:,16]
    print('testY Shape: ', testX.shape)
    print('testY Shape: ', testY.shape)

    # Training
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, n_epoch=100, validation_set=(testX, testY), show_metric=True)

    # Predict the future values
    predictY = model.predict(testX)

    print("---------TEST ERROR-----------")
    expected = np.array(testY).flatten()
    predicted = np.array(predictY).flatten()
    error = sum(((expected - predicted) **2)/len(expected))
    print(error)`enter code here`
```

The output is below.

```
Training Step: 49  | total loss: 24915.56836 | time: 0.557s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 24915.56836 - binary_acc: 0.0000 -- iter: 3136/3150

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-e193b95cc714> in <module>()
----> 1 myRNN()

<ipython-input-129-b039a187b4c6> in myRNN()
     37     # Training
     38     model = tflearn.DNN(net)
---> 39     model.fit(trainX, trainY, n_epoch=100, validation_set=(testX, testY), show_metric=True)
     40 
     41     # Predict the future values

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py in fit(self, X_inputs, Y_targets, n_epoch, validation_set, show_metric, batch_size, shuffle, snapshot_epoch, snapshot_step, excl_trainops, validation_batch_size, run_id, callbacks)
    214                          excl_trainops=excl_trainops,
    215                          run_id=run_id,
--> 216                          callbacks=callbacks)
    217 
    218     def fit_batch(self, X_inputs, Y_targets):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py in fit(self, feed_dicts, n_epoch, val_feed_dicts, show_metric, snapshot_step, snapshot_epoch, shuffle_all, dprep_dict, daug_dict, excl_trainops, run_id, callbacks)
    337                                                        (bool(self.best_checkpoint_path) | snapshot_epoch),
    338                                                        snapshot_step,
--> 339                                                        show_metric)
    340 
    341                             # Update training state

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py in _train(self, training_step, snapshot_epoch, snapshot_step, show_metric)
    845             if show_metric and self.metric is not None:
    846                 eval_ops.append(self.metric)
--> 847             e = evaluate_flow(self.session, eval_ops, self.test_dflow)
    848             self.val_loss = e[0]
    849             if show_metric and self.metric is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py in evaluate_flow(session, ops_to_evaluate, dataflow)
    996 
    997         while feed_batch:
--> 998             r = session.run(ops_to_evaluate, feed_batch)
    999             current_batch_size = get_current_batch_size(feed_batch, dataflow)
   1000             for i in range(len(r)):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    887     try:
    888       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 889                          run_metadata_ptr)
    890       if run_metadata:
    891         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1094                 'Cannot feed value of shape %r for Tensor %r, '
   1095                 'which has shape %r'
-> 1096                 % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
   1097           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
   1098             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 15) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 16, 1)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are creating `trainX`, you only take 15 values and not 16.

Writing `trainX = csvData[0:3360,0:15]` only gives you the first 15 channels in the second dimension. Replace it with `trainX = csvData[0:3360,0:16]`.

And your testing data has the same issue, with the bonus of not being `reshape`d before feeding it to the network. This results in not having the right number of dimensions either.

Comment: I updated the coded, according to the suggestion, now I'm getting a different error.

Comment: trainX Shape:  (100, 16)
trainY Shape:  (100,)
Reshaped trainX:  (100, 16, 1)
Reshaped trainY:  (100, 1)
Reshaped testX:  (100, 16, 1)
Reshaped testY:  (100, 1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: All I needed to do after adjusting the code according to the suggestion, was restart the Kernel with Jupyter Notework. Everything worked after that, thank you Sunreef!! It tough being the newbie. :)